# how to force timeout on python's request library (including DNS lookup)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Python's requests library only supports timeout on **connect** and **read**
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts

There is no way to force a timeout when DNS lookup takes a very long time. I would like to trigger time out when it takes more than X seconds to complete GET request (including DNS, connect and read).

Note that I cannot use **signal** based approach since it works only in main thread.

I am looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: You'll propably need some monkey patch in `urllib3` or `socket` for that..

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible to interrupt an underlying `getaddrinfo` C standard library function other than a signal.

So IMHO you can only overcome your problem with multi-processing - for example an elegant approach using [timeout_decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator) module:

```
@timeout_decorator.timeout(5, use_signals=False)
def timed_get(url):
  return requests.get(url)
```

But remember that this would create a process for each request.